# Phpinfo() shows older version of Mysql Centos 6.7

Tags: mysql, centos, version, php

I have installed Centos 6.7 and installed LAMP(Appache,Mysql,Php) last version and all working good but when i tested phpinfo() the mysql shows:

---

```
$ Client API library version :  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555
```

my server detailes

```
$[root@Univ ~]# httpd -v
$Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

---

```
$[root@Univ ~]# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27, for Linux (x86_64)
```

---

```
$[root@Univ ~]# php -v
PHP 5.6.14 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2015 14:07:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
```

---

many of my scripts like Ojs pkp not working now just showing a blanck page whent trying to install Hope You can Help me
this is an image from my phpinfo()
[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akl60.jpg)

Comment: i saw your image and it is showing about the mysql client api information .can you please elaborate more?
as i saw your mysql details it means that you have a mysql server which version is 5.6.27 and mysql client api version is 5.0.11

Comment: [root@Univ ~]# rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-community-client-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-common-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-server-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-5.6.14-1.el6.remi.x86_64
mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
[root@Univ ~]#

Comment: all is package name please make sure that it is installed
in centos you can check that specific package is installed or not
sudo yum list installed | grep package name

Comment: i run the command yum list installed and i found the '' php-mysqlnd.x86_64                                                              5.6.14-1.el6.remi '' in red color what's that mean

Comment: i have php-mysqlnd and php-mysql installed i think this the problem how to solve it

Comment: php-mysqlnd is mysql server not a php mysql api extension so you should install the php extension of mysql api
i am not sure about that what is meaning red color but this api extension is not installed because api extension name would be like this "php55-mysqlnd.x86_64"

where 55 is php version and x86_64 is system arcitecture

Comment: run a comman sudo yum list available | grep mysql and put all name in comment so that i can sugges you which one you need to install

Comment: thank you very much for your help